# Python venv is giving errno 2 in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-venv

I tried to make a virtual environment as stated in the documentation of the visual studio code. I have already installed python 3.7.3 and anaconda on the system.

I did the following and I'm using vs code version 1.34 and windows 10:

I made an empty folder and used this line of code as stated in official documentation:

```
py -3 -m venv .venv
```

I expected a folder named .venv that has scripts folder with 'activate' file in it. As i have tested this method which worked on other systems with the same configuration, But instead i get the below error message:

```
Error: [Errno 2]: no such file or directory : 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\venv\\scripts\\nt\\python.exe'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It look like installer is broken, or so...

Copy from Python 3 installation folder:

C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37

Files: python.exe, python.pdb, python_d.exe, python_d.pdb, pythonw.exe & pythonw.pdb to folder: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\venv\scripts\nt\

Answer (score -1):

That's because, in the python version you are trying create virtual environment venv [ in other cases -> vitualenv] has not been installed.

> environment building process fails after python global version hand over to the specific version.

you can get idea how to install vitualenv on a specific version from the link below.
[Dealing with multiple python versions and pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/dealing-with-multiple-python-versions-and-pip)